# How to center a progressbar in screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview, android-progressbar

The progress bar is appearing on the left of the screen.  I would want it centered, like in the example.

[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/semi_circle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relative">

        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible" />


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/lilPolicy"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you share full layout code

Comment: Add android:layout_centerInParent="true" property to make it in center.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the `ProgressBar` outside the `ScrollView`, because logically you can know the height of the `ScrollView` at Runtime, so you can't figure out where  the `ProgressBar` will place until running your app.

So, get out the ProgressBar from the `ScrollView`, create another root layout, wrap both `ProgressBar` & `ScrollView` in it; I picked `RelativeLayout` as the root, you can decide another layout manager if you wish.

`layout_centerInParent` attribute is used to center a view within a `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/semi_circle"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lilPolicy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">


            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: I don't know what you're going to accomplish, so I left `android:background="@drawable/semi_circle` in the root layout

Answer (score 1):

> Inside your scrollView

Using **RelativeLayout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using **ConstraintLayout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ConstraintLayout to your project, [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

You can easily implement it.

The way I would have done it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/item_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/item_2"
                android:background="#0000FF"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/item_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/item_1"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/item_3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/item_2"
                android:background="#FFFF00"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_2" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        >
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: add description

Comment: Do avoid nesting!

Answer (score 0):

If you have used relative layout as a parent layout . so we need to add this attribute   `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to align view in parent center. and  scroll view by default remove extra spacing in view . add `android:fillViewport="true"` to make scroll view match parent

> Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relative">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lilPolicy"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

use **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** as you are using **RelativeLayout**.

Comment: or You can use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"